# Why does YouTube return HTTP status code 200 for removed videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, http-status-codes

I have many bookmarked YouTube videos that have been removed. I noticed that most of them return the status code 200. For example:

```
curl -I http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YPvlGFyI5k
```

returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Why doesn't YouTube return 404 or something similar as most sites do when attempting to access an unavailable resource? The significance of this is that bookmark scanners/cleaners do not detect these bookmarks as broken links.

I know how to check the status of YouTube videos using the Data API. I'm making an extension right now that will remedy this problem. I'm just curious why YouTube functions this way.

Comment: The *resource* is alright, its the *data content* that is blocked.

Comment: If the data content is blocked, this would imply that the video still resides on YouTube servers, as I believe it does, since uploaders have a chance to dispute a copyright claim. In this case wouldn't it make sense to give a more appropriate status code like [451 - Legally Restricted Status](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-tbray-http-legally-restricted-status/?include_text=1).

Comment: and this creates great misunderstanding. I've found this blocked video, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmUnXwfn-yY - from there, I still can get valid *content* which is: username who posted video, similar videos, probably some comments, description.

Can't find a better example. 'Most of them return the status code 200' - may we see some other examples?

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen a blocked video like that, where the username and title are displayed. If this additional information is present, then I can see how the resource is still valid. However, all the broken links I have do not have this metadata present, they usually say that the video is unavailable, such as these: [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RB47ALtocKU](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RB47ALtocKU), [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwWqmsCaj0Y&feature=player_embedded](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwWqmsCaj0Y&feature=player_embedded)

Comment: This is, indeed, a frustration. Youtube videos seem particularly prone to linkrot, yet we cannot use the standard available mechanism for checking. Like you say, using the api is an alternative, but it means youtube has to be made a special case, and a lot more effort has to go into checking one of the prime causes of broken links!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I don't think it would be proper to return a 404 for a copyright violation error. Maybe a "410 Gone" would be acceptable. Youtube return a 404 for videos that were never there, on the other hand.